# Percentage Symbol in Pivot Table (Graph View) Odoo V8

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to add a percentage symbol (%) to a field of type float in measure in a pivot Table Odoo v8

[image]

I want in this measure column to show number as percentage

### **Result that i have in the table : 50.00**

### **Result that i want : 50.00%**

here is my code xml :

```
<record id="view_order_product_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
     <field name="name">forecast_report.graph</field>
     <field name="model">forecast_report</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <graph string="Forecasts Analysis" type="pivot">
            <!--  <field name="date" interval="month" type="col"/> -->
             <field name="forecast_quantity" type="measure"/>
             <field name="product_uom_qty" type="measure"/>
             <field name="forecast_subtotal" type="measure"/>
             <field name="price_total" type="measure"/>
             <field name="percentage_forecast"  type="measure"/>
             <field name="product_id" type="row"/>
         </graph>
     </field>
</record>
```

Code python of the forecast_percentage :

```
'percentage_forecast': fields.float('% Sales Forecast', readonly=True,  group_operator = 'avg'),
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can add manually `%` sign in your xml file after following line.

```
    <field name="percentage_forecast"  type="measure"/>
```

Comment: I already try it, but it does not change anything in the graph :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **widget**, try this way:

```xml
<field name="percentage_forecast"  type="measure" widget="percentage"/>
```

I use it this way and it works for me.